# List package dependencies for Microsoft.Graph

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have issues with conflicting packages across many projects inside a solution. When i use the ui to manage nuget packages i can see the dependencies and version numbers in the ui. How do i do this using the package console manager? This seems like a really simple thing, but i'm struggling to find the answer online for asp.net framework. I want to list dependencies for microsoft.graph using the package console manager.

Online i get responses like, Get-PackageDependencies Microsoft.Graph, but this is not recognised in package manager or powershell.